# Gas Generator Stalls Every Few Seconds

Tags: stall, carburetor, generator

This is a Champion Global Power Equiptment 9000 Peak Watts/7000 Running Watts (Gasoline) 8100 Peak Watts/6300 Running Watts (LPG) Electric Start Dual Fuel Generator. The following is a video of what happens when I try to keep in running.

https://youtu.be/F0pVER1uySc

It keeps stalling but when I spray a little bit of carb cleaner in the intake it keeps running. I'm thinking it needs the carburetor opened up a little to not keep stalling. Which screw do I turn to loosen the carburetor?

Is it either of these?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it! Turns out it was the second screw (the black one). I turned it 1 turn counter clockwise and the generator has been running great for 20 minutes!

Comment: Glad you were able to fix it and appreciate you posting what you did to do so. :o)